Django is mixing 2 different translation entries and creates a fuzzy entry in the PO file
I see this in the django.po file after executing python manage.py makemessages command:
#: .\homepage\models.py:40
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "The logo of the site as appears on the top of each page."
msgid "The logo of the brand as appears on the homepage."
msgstr "لوگوی سایت که بالای هر صفحه نمایش داده می‌شود."

The problem:
#| msgid "The logo of the site as appears on the top of each page." belongs to line 20 (not 40) of models.py of core app (not homepage). There's no other entry for line 20 of models.py of the core app in the file.
msgid "The logo of the brand as appears on the homepage." belongs to line 40 of models.py of homepage app.
Ironically, the translated text appears for the first message (which is commented out) not the second.
I have no idea why this is happening and how to fix it.
This is Django v5.0.3 on Windows.

Yes if I delete the po file and run makemessages command again, the fuzzy entry disappears, along with all of my translations :(

can You show us your models.py where you are emitting these messages, settings.py where you are setting the langues

That translation is marked as fuzzy because it is autogenerated. You are supposed to review / update that translation and remove the fuzzy marker by removing the latter two comments.

@AbdulAzizBarkat The issue is I don't understand what is wrong with my translation. The only thing they have in common is that they both are the help_text of a model field but in two different apps. And I think removing the comment is not enough and I have to manually add the missing entry to the PO file? And if yes, what happens when I run the makemessages command again?

msgid "The logo of the site as appears on the top of each page." is most likely not missing. It should be present somewhere else in your .po file. When you ran makemessages it inferred that The logo of the brand as appears on the homepage. is somewhat similar to the other string and autogenerated a translation for you.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Well it is missing entirely :( Is there any hack to disable the fuzzy thing?

"Ironically, the translated text appears for the first message" would imply the entry is actually there. This one is ignored as it is marked as fuzzy. See the duplicate.
